# Using `With[...]` with a list specification as a variable

Tags: evaluation, scoping, expression-construction

If you have some defined function, say `f[a_, b_ c_, x]`, one can initialize this by using `With[...]` as

```
With[
       {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3},
       f[a, b c, x]
]
```

However I would like to be able to put my variable specification list into its own variable as:

```
InitializationList = {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3};
```

And then use it in the argument of the `With[...]` as

```
  With[
           InitializationList ,
           f[a, b, c, x]
    ]
```

However *Mathematica* 12.0 complains with saying that `InitializationList` is not a list of variable specifications. I have tried using `Evaluate` and `Holdform`, but I get the same error.

Any suggestions to achieve what I want or an alternative process?

Comment: Try using Trace to see what is happening

Comment: @JackLaVigne Thanks for that tip. Great diagnostic tool

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the standard tricks I learn on this site is this:

```
init = Hold[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}];
init /. Hold[v_] :> With[v, f[a, b, c, x]]

(*  f[1, 2, 3, x]  *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a whirl and get back to you!

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to use delayed assignment in the first argument of `With`:

```
With[{init := {a = 1, b = 2}},
 With[init, {a, b}]]
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

Or if you prefer to store your variable specification list as an `OwnValue`:

```
init := {a = 1, b = 2}
Unevaluated[With[init, {a, b}]] /. OwnValues[init]
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

Comment: Also a perfectly valid solution, very nice.