# Handling a list of variable assignments to be used with `With`

Tags: replacement, scoping

Is there a way to use `With` as follows?

```
variables := {a = 2, b = 3};
With[variables, a^b]
```

Desired output

```
8
```

Obviously the above code will actually just output

```
With[variables, a^b]
```

I know I can do something similar to this by defining a list of rules and using the operator form of `ReplaceAll`, I just like the way the `With` syntax looks and would prefer to use it if possible.

Comment: Hmm… I don't think it's a good idea, once the `variables` is executed somewhere, `a` and `b` will be polluted.

Comment: Related: [(3864)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3864/121), [(19758)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19758/121), [(28610)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/121), [(31708)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31708/121), [(69590)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This question is exact duplicate of [(204116)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204116/280).

Comment: @Alexey do you think *that one* should be marked as a duplicate too? Is `With`/`Block` distinct enough to keep it separate from [(24036)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24036/121)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In principle, yes, it should be market as a duplicate too.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks! Yes this is a duplicate. Actually can I ask how you found that question? It was very difficult for me to successfully search for this question just because `With` is a common preposition.

Comment: @Diffycue Heh, it was simple: I answered that question and simply remembered this when saw your question. But generally when searching it is helps to use appropriate tag(s): we are doing hard work on assigning appropriate tags for questions and it really helps a lot when you need to find somthing specific. In this case the tag `scoping` would help.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks so much! Btw I will be using your answer to that question since it best matches the kind of syntax I am after

Answer (score 4):

A quick idiomatic approach is to do

```
Unevaluated[explicitExpression] /. OwnValues[variableWithSetDelayedDefinition]
```

You can find it in [76917](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76917/how-to-properly-inject-iterators-into-table/76919#76919) together with alternatives. See linked topics as well.

So here:

```
variables := {a = 2, b = 3};

With[variables, a^b] // Unevaluated // ReplaceAll @ OwnValues @ variables
```

> 8

Comment: Linked topic or related ones do not seem to be close enough to be a duplicate but there is probably a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: I reviewed the related questions and found a couple that I think work; let me know if you agree.  Incidentally I reopened one of them, despite the fact that I was the one who closed it, because it really doesn't seem like a duplicate to me now. *shrug*